# is there is any function in php to get the specific keys from a multi dimensional arrray

Tags: php

I want to get the three keys from a multidimensional array in php

for example:

```
[
    [0]=>[
        'name'     => 'appetizers',
        'category' => 'category1',
        'price'    => 20,
        'desc'     => 'best in it\'s category',
        'brand'    => 'abc'
    ],
    [1]=>[
        'name'     => 'appetizers',
        'category' => 'category2',
        'price'    => 30,
        'desc'     => 'best in it\'s category',
        'brand'    => 'abc2'
    ]
]
```

the keys I want are `name`, `price` and `desc` 
I can do this by using loops but i am just curious whether there is any function like array_column as this provide single column with indexing.

the output i want is somewhat like this:

```
[
        [0]=>[
            'name'     => 'appetizers',
            'price'    => 20,
            'desc'     => 'best in it\'s category'
        ],
        [1]=>[
            'name'     => 'appetizers',
            'price'    => 30,
            'desc'     => 'best in it\'s category',
        ]
    ]

OR this can also be beneficial

[
        [0]=>[
              'appetizers',
              20,
            'best in it\'s category'
        ],
        [1]=>[
             'appetizers',
            30,
            'best in it\'s category',
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: you want to extract keys or there corresponding values?

Comment: You need to use array_keys http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php (you should also learn to use Google before asking people basic stuff)

Comment: i want to extract keys with their corresponding values if possible....if not corresponding values will work for me

Comment: Did you try array_keys?

Comment: what final output you want? add that in your question. As well as please add your attempts too.

Comment: Did you check the manual? The [PHP manual lists all of the functions dealing with arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). It would take you all of one minute to determine if such a function exists.

Comment: A combination of `array_walk` or `array_map` and `array_intersect_keys` will do…

Comment: Have you tried `$_arr[$i]['name']` ?

Comment: @Samuel for this we need to use loop...but i want to do it with a function